# What is infinite product of indiscrete typology？

Tags: general-topology

> What is infinite product of indiscrete typology？

Finite product of indiscrete space is indiscrete because it's basis is $\{X \times \cdots \times X \}$. But what about infinite product case?

I think $\{X\times\cdots\}$　is basis, so it is indiscrete in terms of box topology.

But how can I prove this topology is also indiscrete in terms of product topology (weakest topology whose projection is continuous)？

Comment: Remember that a basis for $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is $\prod_{i\in I}U_i$ for $U_i\subset X_i$ open, where $U_i=X_i$ for all but finitely many $i$. But open subsets are either $\emptyset$ or $X_i$. If there is any $i$ with $U_i=\emptyset$ then the entire product is empty, so the basis is just $\{\emptyset,\prod_{i\in I}X_i\}$.

Comment: By the way, box topology is always finer than product topology, so box topology being indiscrete immediately tells you the product topology is indiscrete.

Comment: Than you. Is it easy to prove box topology is finer than product topology？

Comment: Yes, it is almost by definition.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but product top is defined as weakest top whose proj is conti, and box top is defined as top whose basis is generated from product of basis of each component. How can I confirm each open set with product top is open with box top？

Comment: Check that the projection maps from box topology to its components are continuous. Then, minimality gives you what you want.

Comment: @KentaS . Something surprising (to me) is that it is still unknown whether the box top on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ is normal $(T_4)$ or not.